# Return all items from MySQL table, but check if they are a favourite item based on second table

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MySQL called 'courses'. It has an ID field and a course name amongst other fields.
I can return all courses with the following query

```
SELECT * FROM courses ORDER BY `name`
```

I then have a second table called 'favourites' which has two fields, courseid and userid. I am using it so users can favourite courses.

What I am trying to do is change my query so that it for each course aswell as returning the course name and other fields from the courses table, I would like it to return a boolean value of 0 or 1 if that course has been favourited by the user.

I know I have to pass the userID with the query but I am unsure how to construct the query.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

If the `favourites` table can have at most one row per user, then this will do what you want:

```
SELECT c.*, (f.courseid IS NOT NULL) as FavouriteBy2Flag
FROM courses c LEFT JOIN
     favourites f
     ON f.courseid = c.courseid AND f.userid = 2 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have framed the query based on your description

a) For all the courses

```
SELECT c.*, IF(f.courseid IS NULL, '1', '0') FROM
courses c
LEFT JOIN favourites f ON(f.courseid = c.courseid)
GROUP BY c.courseid
```

b) For all courses against specific userid(here I used userid = 2)

```
SELECT c.*, IF(f.courseid IS NULL, '1', '0') FROM
courses c
LEFT JOIN favourites f ON(f.courseid = c.courseid)
WHERE f.userid = '2' 
GROUP BY c.courseid
```